# Strip words after @

Tags: javascript

How do I strip out the words after the @? for example if string is

```
12 @ 8.97 MB
```

then the output would become

```
12
```

How to do this in javascript?

Comment: `'12 @ 8.97 MB'.split('@')[0];`

Comment: if you strip out the words after the @ sign, then you get `12 @` not `12` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just `split` it, if there is no `@` char, it'll just return an array of 1 string, if there was an `@`, everything that preceded the `@`, will be assigned to the first (`0`) index of the resulting array. In other words:

```
 var preAt = someString.split('@')[0];
```

It doesn't matter if the string contained 0 or 1000 *at* signs, this will work

Comment: for a 1000 *at* signs, `.split('@', 2);` might be better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var index = str.indexOf('@', 0);
if (index != -1)
    var output = str.substring(0, index);
else 
    var output = str;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I just tried your code but it doesn't work. here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/7Qj3Y/

Comment: If there was no `@`-sign, this code reads `str.substring(0,-2)`, if the `@` was the first char, it reads `str.substring(0,-1)`... just _use split_

Comment: hmm i just tried in VS and it did not work until  I added the start position parameter (which I thought was optional). 
And yes, if @ is not present, the code won't work. Editing it so it works in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var mystring = "12@something";
return mystring.substring('@')[0];
```